# Please help me get rid of this empty strip in the footer

Tags: css

I can't seem to get rid of the strip of empty space at the very bottom of [this site](http://wholefoodforhorses.com/). I'm using Firebug and don't see any padding/margins anywhere. Anyone have a clue?

It is the beige strip in the image below:

[image]

Comment: please add the code to http://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: Try adding height:100% to HTML, BODY and your main wrapper DIV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extra space is being caused by the line-height property of the xg_foot div

You need to change your #xg_foot css to this:

```
#xg_foot {
    box-shadow: none !important;
    font-family: 'bitter',serif;
    height: 23px; /* Adjust to your liking */
    line-height: 0;
    padding: 13px 0 0; /* Adjust to your liking */
    width: 100% !important;
}
```